# How to control font size in png?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, figure, r-grid

I am trying to make figures for a manuscript, that should be written with MS Word, which does not accept figures in pdf format. The journal asks first draft with figures embedded in the Word file. These figures should have resolution minimum of 300 dpi and have a width of either 169 mm or 81 mm (two/one column). I notice that when I specify the resolution of the picture to 300 (res = 300), the font size is bound to this value. This works fine with some figures (the first example, example.png), and worse with others (example2.png). How can I control the font size so that the dimensions and resolution of the figure remain fixed?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data(iris)

vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Length))
q <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Petal.Width))
len <- p + geom_boxplot()
wid <- q + geom_boxplot()

png("example.png", width = 169, height = 100, units = "mm", res = 300)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(len, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(wid, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
dev.off()

png("example2.png", width = 81, height = 100, units = "mm", res = 300)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(len, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(wid, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
dev.off()
```

In other words, I would like to decrease the font size in example2.png, but keep the layout and dimensions of the two plots as they are.

[image: example.png]
Example.png

[image: example2.png]
Example2.png

Comment: I don't understand: Example1.png is physically twice as wide as Example2.png, so if you display both images full-page width like here the second one should be expanded and the font appear larger. If you display/print them both at 1:1 zoom (real size) the font and resolution should be identical, no?

Comment: Well, no, I guess. This is what I thought too, but the font seems to be somehow constant. You see the overlapping species names. If the font size was connected to the device size, then the labels in Example2.png wouldn't overlap? I think this is because pointsize and res are connected in png function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `base_size` argument to the `theme_XXX()` function, you can change the overall font sizes for all the text.

```
png("example2.png", width = 81, height = 100, units = "mm", res = 300)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(len + theme_gray(base_size=12*(81/169)), vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(wid + theme_gray(base_size=12*(81/169)), vp = vplayout(1, 2))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for being closer to the question. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Perfect! I wouldn't have found this out on my own. Worth asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Simply change the `pointsize` attribute of png. For example:

```
png(filename="plot4.png", width=580, height=700, pointsize=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the fontsize is the same regardless of the resolution and device size. You can check it in the following examples:

```
library(grid)

png("example1.png", width = 30, height = 5, units = "mm", res = 200)
g <- grid.text("testing font size", gp=gpar(fontsize=12))
width <- convertUnit(grobWidth(g), "mm")
height <- convertUnit(grobHeight(g), "mm", "y")
grid.rect(width=width, height=height, gp=gpar(lty=2, fill=NA))
dev.off()


png("example2.png", width = 60, height = 5, units = "mm", res = 500)
grid.text("testing font size", gp=gpar(fontsize=12))
grid.rect(width=width, height=height, gp=gpar(lty=2, fill=NA))
dev.off()
```

But it seems you actually wanted to change the font size.

Comment: Yes it seems to be. I wanted to get control over the font size, because the labels were overlapping in example2.png. Brian Diggs example solved it perfectly in this case, but you're right that the approach you suggest might be more useful, since the font size should be the same in every figure.