# Why is the axis label in R graphics dependent on the output picture size

Tags: r, axis-labels

I want to create figures that perfectly match the requirements of certain journals. They usually ask for a axis label between 6-8 points.
So far, I used the following commands within the png() command:

```
pointsize=1,width=8,height=6, units="cm", res=300
```

and within parameters par():

```
cex.axis=6,cex.lab=8, cex=1
```

My axis commands look like that:

```
axis(2,at=seq(0.7,1.1,0.1),labels=seq(0.7,1.1,0.1),
     lwd=1.5,lwd.ticks=1.5,las=1,cex.axis=6)
```

The issue is the following:
When I create a smaller picture (like 4x6 cm) this set of commands works perfectly fine, e.g. I obtain a picture with an axis label in 6 points.
However, when I create bigger pictures like (16x9 cm) the axis labels are printed smaller than 6 points, which is super annoying. I do not have a clue what's happening.

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30716567/322912)?